# Groupbox redraw issue

Tags: c#, paint, redraw

I feel like I've scoured the internet for an answer but i still haven't solved this problem.
I am building a hangman game in C# (which I'm still new to) and I have a groupbox on my form where I am drawing the different "body parts". The problem is that it is redrawn over every time the draw event is called. So i'll end up with a head, then just an arm, a leg, etc.

I've tried to do things like overriding the OnPaintBackground, and while this solves the problem with the redrawing, it screws up the entire form and it looks awful when I do this.
I've also tried to draw onto a panel instead of a groupbox but for some reason I couldn't get it to even draw.

Could anyone offer any suggestions? 
This is NOT homework by the way, just a personal project and learning experience.

Some code: this is what I'm using to trigger the draw function (it triggers on other conditions I have)

```
this.groupBoxHang.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.groupBoxHangMan_Paint);
```

Then it comes to here and it calls the actual function, which is in a separate class

```
    private void groupBoxHangMan_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {          
       draw.DrawHangMan(e.Graphics, GetRemainingGuess());      
    }
```

Here is part of the other class:

```
    public void DrawHangMan(Graphics dM, int guessesRemaining)
    {        
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

        Pen deathPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
        deathPen.Width = 2.0F;

        if (guessesRemaining == 7)
        {
            dM.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 94, 75, 60, 60);//head
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 6)
        {
            dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 124, 210, 124, 135);//body
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 5)
        {
            dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 170, 65, 145);//left arm
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 4)
        {
            dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 170, 181, 145); //right arm
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 3)
        {
            dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 210, 65, 255);//left leg
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 2)
        {
            dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 210, 181, 255);//right leg
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 1)
        {
            dM.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 105, 93, 10, 10); //left open eye
            dM.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 133, 93, 10, 10); //right open eye
        }
        else if (guessesRemaining == 0)
        {
            dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 102, 104, 118, 92);//left eye dead
            dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 118, 104, 102, 92);

            dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 130, 104, 146, 92);//right dead eye
            dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 146, 104, 130, 92);
        }         

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things with your If statements. They are set to only activate when it is equal to the count so you keep from redrawing when the count is less than the threshold, the second thing is that with your else statements you only run one of the levels. Doing it in your `Paint` event is correct. Try something like this:

```
public void DrawHangMan(Graphics dM, int guessesRemaining)
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
    Pen deathPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
    deathPen.Width = 2.0F;

    if (guessesRemaining < 8)
    {
        dM.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 94, 75, 60, 60);//head
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 7)
    {
        dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 124, 210, 124, 135);//body
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 6)
    {
        dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 170, 65, 145);//left arm
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 5)
    {
        dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 170, 181, 145); //right arm
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 4)
    {
        dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 210, 65, 255);//left leg
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 3)
    {
        dM.DrawLine(blackPen, 123, 210, 181, 255);//right leg
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 2)
    {
        dM.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 105, 93, 10, 10); //left open eye
        dM.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 133, 93, 10, 10); //right open eye
    }
    if (guessesRemaining < 1)
    {
        dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 102, 104, 118, 92);//left eye dead
        dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 118, 104, 102, 92);
        dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 130, 104, 146, 92);//right dead eye
        dM.DrawLine(deathPen, 146, 104, 130, 92);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hadn't even thought of doing it like this, mostly because I was trying to fix it clearing in the first place. This works pretty well though, even if it is redrawing the parts each time. I'm still curious though. Is their a better way to do this where you wouldn't need to redraw the same parts more than once? I assume it has to do with the OnPaint and OnPaintBackground calls.

Comment: @AarinCovyeau The drawing routine is going to have to be able to draw the complete picture if the Form is invalidated, The only ways that I know to alleviate some of the drawing would be to create regions and only invalidate them when you change your state, but you would still need to have code like I gave you above or create a Bitmap draw to that then update a picturebox or simular with the image.